# Unsure about expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

Hello, can someone tell me how this expression is expanded in this proof. Does it follow from some other theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the standard $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}) = (a-b)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-j}b^j.$$

applied to $a=(z-z_0 )$, $b=(z-z_0-h)$

together with $$\frac{1}{b^n}-\frac{1}{a^n}=\frac{a^n-b_n}{a^nb^n}.$$